Are we allowed to start a new business during chatur mas?
So,
Chaturmas is about to begin. And everywhere it is mentioned that manglik karya should not be done during these four months. Does starting a business count as a manglik karya?
Does that mean we should not start new business during these four months? Can we start a new job?
I have come across a few reports that say even starting a new business must be avoided. They also say no gruh praves, no engagement, etc. However, I have a Shri Mahalaxmi panchange(I am maharashtrian) and it has muhurats for engagement, vastuk shanti, bhumi pujan, etc(No wedding muhurats) during chaturmas.What can we do if we cant wait for four months.
Here is one such reportExternal link to a report on chaturmas
For long I have not been able to earn and I have a small business opportunity now. And it starts right at the beginning of the chaturmas.
I am a maharashtrian.
Please guide me.
